# Calculate visits in BQ using Adobe Analytics data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, adobe-analytics

I am trying to calculate the total number of visits per day by extracting the raw data from Adobe Analytics in Big Query. I have limited skill in writing SQL queries, therefore I would really appreciate if someone could point out what I am doing wrong.

Query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM date_time) AS Day, 
CONCAT(visid_high, "-", visid_low, "-", visit_start_time_gmt) AS visits 
FROM `adobe_data.table1` WHERE date_time > '2019-05-01' AND date_time < '2019-05-30' 
AND page_event = '0' 
AND exclude_hit = '0'
GROUP by Day;
```

The error I get is: "Select list expression column visits_high which is neither grouped not aggregated."

Note: I do not want to group by 'visits', I am trying to get visits by 'Day' (such as on 2019-05-01, visits was 12555).

Comment: What are you trying to do with the CONCAT function? That function does a string concatenation between the columns listed, so the output of that would be something like '555-3-7:30' if visid_high = 555, visid_low = 3, and visit_start_time_gmt = 7:30. And since it is combining discrete values like that, they will need to be included in the GROUP BY statement. I think you're looking for an Aggregate function like SUM if you are trying to total columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to an aggregation function for the second expression.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM date_time) AS Day, 
       ARRAY_AGG(CONCAT(visid_high, '-', visid_low, '-', visit_start_time_gmt)) AS visits 
FROM `adobe_data.table1`
WHERE date_time > '2019-05-01' AND date_time < '2019-05-30' AND
      page_event = '0' AND
      exclude_hit = '0'
GROUP by Day;
```